# Login to Google from iFrame

Tags: authentication, iframe, joomla, openid

I have seen that it is not possible to display any Google page from an iframe. An error message is displayed: cannot display, open in a new window.

I need to login to Google (OpenId authentication) from an iFrame in Joomla (cannot change this). Is there a workaround for this? I thought I could open the authentication page in a new window, and then try to kill that window and reload the original one, but I am not sure I can do that.

Thanks

Comment: Google, (nor Facebook for instance) will allow embedding in an iFrame.

Comment: You would have to redirect or show a pop up. As Mathieu said, major companies have blocked embedding http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking#X-Frame-Options

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well you can just get the form (html code) and put it in your iframe but this will get very messy, for example, there maybe certain JS files that you need to include as well.

Redirecting to Google is best way to implement it.As Using IFrame Sometime does not allowed by some Companies Due to Security.